# Incompatibility of zref-perpage and amsmath

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility, zref

If `amsmath` is loaded after `zref-perpage`, `zref-perpage` will not reset counters in each page. What should be done to fix this except changing the loading order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is a test \footnote{test}
\newpage
This is another test \footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both packages `zref-perpage` and `amstext` (loaded by package `amsmath`) redefine `\stepcounter` to add some code. Package `zref-perpage` keeps the `\stepcounter` it finds, but `amstext` overwrites `\stepcounter` deleting the additions of `zref-perpage`.

Thus loading `zref-perpage` *after* `amstext`/`amsmath` is the correct workaround.

In the next version of `zref` the module `zref-perpage` will check for `amstext` and its redefinition of `\stepcounter` and will fix it.